# Restriction on @OneToMany mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a product class where there is an @OneToMany association for a list of buyers. What I want to do is that buyer search performed by the association when I search for a product, use a null constraint for the end date column of the Buyer table. How to do this in a list mapping like this, below.

```
// it would be something I needed cri.createCriteria("listaBuyer", "buyer).add(Restriction.isNull("finalDate"));
```

**Example**

**Registered data**

```
product code   |    initial date     | final date    | 
-------------------------------------------------------
  1            |  2016-28-07         |  2017-28-07   | 
 ------------------------------------------------------
  2            |  2016-10-08         |  2017-28-07   | 
 ------------------------------------------------------
  3            |  2017-28-08         |               | 
 -----------------------------------------------------
  4            |  2017-30-08         |               |
```

**Product Class**

```
public class Product {

@OneToMany(targetEntity=Buyer.class, orphanRemoval=true, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy="product")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
public List<Buyer> getListaBuyer() {
    if (listaBuyer == null) {
        listaBuyer = new ArrayList<Buyer>();
    }
    return listaBuyer;
}
```

**built criterion**

```
Criteria cri = getSession().createCriteria(Product.class);
    cri.createCriteria("status", "sta");

    cri.add(Restrictions.eq("id", Product.getId()));


    return cri.list();
```

**Expected outcome**

```
product code   |    initial date     | final date    | 
-------------------------------------------------------
  3            |  2017-28-08         |               | 
 -----------------------------------------------------
  4            |  2017-30-08         |               |
```

**Returned result**

```
product code   |    initial date     | final date    | 
-------------------------------------------------------
  1            |  2016-28-07         |  2017-28-07   | 
 ------------------------------------------------------
  2            |  2016-10-08         |  2017-28-07   | 
 ------------------------------------------------------
  3            |  2017-28-08         |               | 
 -----------------------------------------------------
  4            |  2017-30-08         |               |
```